# Skrollr percentage offsets

Tags: javascript, plugins, skrollr

I'm looking for a way to set percentages relative to the **document** height (instead of **viewport** height) with the Skrollr plugin. This is because I want to make a scrolling animation where the whole page scales when you make the window longer or smaller.

I've tried using "data-0p-start" and "data-100p-start" but this behaves like the relative notation instead of the absolute notation.

Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there's not real option for this. Prinzhorn suggested using constant functions, so I'll check that out.
https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/issues/484